# Loop returning bool

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a loop and I need to return certain numbers in a pattern as true I have the `count` at my disposal as well as the number `4` and `4-1(3)`. I need to return 5,12,19,26,33 etc as true and the others as false.

```
function saturn(count,perline){
  var line_one = perline; // 5
  var line_two = perline-1; // 4
  var line_both = line_one + line_two; // 7
  var x = (perline+1)+(line_both*(Math.floor(count/(perline+1))-1));
  if(x<0) x = 0;
  var capture;
  if(perline == 1){ //if perline = 1 don't indent any
    capture = false;
  }else if(x == count){
    capture = true;
  }
  console.log("("+perline+"+1)+("+line_both+"*(Math.floor("+count+"/("+perline+"+1))-1)) ="+x);  
  console.log(count+" "+capture);
  return capture;
}
```

The console output.

```
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(1/(4+1))-1)) =0
script.js:561 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(2/(4+1))-1)) =0
script.js:562 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(3/(4+1))-1)) =0
script.js:563 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(4/(4+1))-1)) =0
script.js:564 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(5/(4+1))-1)) =5
script.js:565 true
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(6/(4+1))-1)) =5
script.js:566 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(7/(4+1))-1)) =5
script.js:567 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(8/(4+1))-1)) =5
script.js:568 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(9/(4+1))-1)) =5
script.js:569 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(10/(4+1))-1)) =12
script.js:5610 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(11/(4+1))-1)) =12
script.js:5611 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(12/(4+1))-1)) =12
script.js:5612 true
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(13/(4+1))-1)) =12
script.js:5613 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(14/(4+1))-1)) =12
script.js:5614 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(15/(4+1))-1)) =19
script.js:5615 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(16/(4+1))-1)) =19
script.js:5616 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(17/(4+1))-1)) =19
script.js:5617 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(18/(4+1))-1)) =19
script.js:5618 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(19/(4+1))-1)) =19
script.js:5619 true
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(20/(4+1))-1)) =26
script.js:5620 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(21/(4+1))-1)) =26
script.js:5621 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(22/(4+1))-1)) =26
script.js:5622 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(23/(4+1))-1)) =26
script.js:5623 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(24/(4+1))-1)) =26
script.js:5624 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(25/(4+1))-1)) =33
script.js:5625 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(26/(4+1))-1)) =33
script.js:5626 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(27/(4+1))-1)) =33
script.js:5627 undefined
script.js:54(4+1)+(7*(Math.floor(28/(4+1))-1)) =33
script.js:5628 undefined
```

Comment: And what have you tried?  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: the algo `(4+1)+(((4-1)+4)*(Math.floor(count/(4+1))-1))` i'm going nuts =[ it works the the first couple of numbers but gets offset later on.

Comment: Consider updating your question with the details of this algorithm you are trying to write and why you can't get it to work.  Examples of expected true/false input will be helpful as well.

Comment: I update it! Please take a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are trying to do?

```
return (x - 5) % 7 == 0
```

It returns true for 5, 12, 19, 26 and 33.

EDIT: you have edited, and I still can't understand what you, but this will not help, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the % operator. This little fiddle demo go through 100 numbers and seems to returned the one you are after. Basically every 7 iteration interation % 7 will be equal to one so just need to add 4 to get your the numbers you are after.

http://jsfiddle.net/NQr5j/

```
var iteration = 100,
    store = [];

do {
    if (iteration % 7 == 1) store.push(iteration + 4);
} while (iteration--);

console.log(store);
```